# CountUP Timer from converted Milliseconds to DateTime

Tags: php, timer

I am trying to create a CountUP timer that will count up the time from a specific date & time format M,d,y,H:i:s

I am having trouble getting the time converted from milliseconds to DateTime to count up the time since that DateTime.

The current code I have is:

```
 <?php 
$gamemodematchhistorystrattime = $data->gameStartTime;
$gamemodematchhistorystrattime = substr($gamemodematchhistorystrattime, 0, -3);
$dtcreatedate = new DateTime("@$gamemodematchhistorystrattime"); // convert UNIX timestamp to PHP DateTime
$dtcreatedate->format('M,d,y,H:i:s');
?>
```

Comment: Where is the JavaScript?

Comment: There is no javascript as it wouldnt work, so im looking for another solution on here

Comment: So why the tag? It will be removed